# Multiplication of two complex numbers in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to figure out how to multiply two complex numbers but I know that it's completely different from the normal multiplication method of complex numbers. I have done this for the addition of two complex numbers, can someone help me out how to do multiplication?

```
%%Z1=X1+Y1 and Z2=X2+Y2.
add(a(X1,X2), a(Y1,Y2), a(Z1,Z2)) :-
  Z1 is X1 + Y1,
  Z2 is X2 + Y2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so much a prolog problem as a maths problem:

```
(x1 + ix2) x (y1 + iy2) = x1(y1 + iy2) + ix2(y1+iy2)
                        = x1y1 + ix1y2 + ix2y1 - x2y2
                        = (x1y1-x2y2) + i(x1y2+x2y1)
```

Therefore, the rule:

```
%%Z1=x1y1-x2y2 and Z2=x1y2+x2y1.
multiply(a(X1,X2), a(Y1,Y2), a(Z1,Z2)) :-
  Z1 is X1 * Y1 - X2 * Y2,
  Z2 is X1* Y2 + X2 * Y1.
```

Comment: That said - it might be better to embed rules of symbolic calculation, and exploit theorem-proving to let apply these rules? This is Prolog after all...